# A jar file doesn't run whit Jasper Reports, doesn't nothing

Tags: jasper-reports

i've tried to run a jar file of my directory dist, this contain Jasper Reports in base a parameter, when i execute it on netbeans, compile correctly all my reports work, but when run the jar file on another computer it doesn't work, the console throws the next message:
Error compiling report java source files : C:\Users\NAME_USER\null_1432143127286_344688.java

I suppose the mistake is when the parameter is called for build the jasper report, is so weird because, when i run the same jar and show other report that no require parameters, it works perfectly. if somebody could help me, please.

The code for compile the jasper:

```
String parameter = combobox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
try {
Connection con =conexion.GetConnection(login.name, login.pass);
String directory = "C:\\Users\\NAME_USER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SISE\\src\\reports\\report1.jrxml";
Map values = new HashMap();
values.put("detail", parameter);
JasperReport reportJasper =            JasperCompileManager.compileReport(directory);
JasperPrint show = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportJasper, values, con);
JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(show,false);            view.setVisible(true); 
} catch (JRException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

in netbeans works, but in jar file executable, nop. thanks